# Generic wrappers with room database

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, mvvm, android-room

I'd like to implement `generic wrapper` of my `room database`. The one I've implement on my own, doesn't seem to use it. Can you help me with it? Firstly, here's some code:

**Wrapper**

```
sealed class MyState{
data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : DatabaseState()
data class Error<out T>(val error: T) : DatabaseState()
}
```

**Repository**

```
    val myCurr: Flow<MyModelClass> =
    mydao.getCurr().shareIn(
        scope, replay = 1, started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()
    )
```

**ViewModel**

```
private val _myState: MutableSharedFlow<MyState<myModel>> = MutableSharedFlow(replay = 1)
val stateGetter: SharedFlow<MyState<myModel>> get() = _myState
    

    fun myFun() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO ) {
        myRepository.myCurr
            .catch { _myState.emit(MyState.Error(it.cause))
            .collect { myModel->
                _myState.emit(DatabaseState.Success(myModel.curr))
            }
    }
}
```

It is still kinda new stuff for me, so the code probably won't be best. I just wondering, if my `Repository` class is correctly. I've read somewhere (probably in documentation) that I shouldn't use functions for getting values from db, instead, I should use val. Is there any way to use `shareIn`, and store it in generic wrapper? Is it good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` properties are appropriate for flows that don't need an input. A function would be necessary when you need to retrieve a flow that is based on a specific input, as @LuisPascual's answer demonstrates. It would not make sense to create a SharedFlow and return it in a function, though, because then each function caller would be getting a different SharedFlow instance (nothing would be shared).

So your repository code is perfect. But your ViewModel code has a couple of issues.

1. You have a function that must be called to make your SharedFlow work. This is pointless convolution. Why not just do this work in an `init` block so it will happen automatically without you having to remember to call `myFun` somewhere, but being super careful not to call `myFun` more than once? If an outside class, such as a Activity calls it when it is created, it will be very difficult to prevent it from being called more than once.
2. Even simpler, just use `shareIn`. Then you don't even need to do the above in an `init` block and you don't need a separate backing MutableSharedFlow property.
3. You don't need to specify a dispatcher to call a Flow from room! Really the only time you should ever be using the `flowOn` operator is in a chain of calls after a `flow { }` builder (or similar) call or a `map` operator that does blocking work, because any Flow you get from another class should already be internally delegating itself appropriately (following the principles of separation of concerns and encapsulation). A Room DAO is never going to return a fragile Flow that requires some specific Dispatcher to avoid blocking a thread.

So all your ViewModel code above should be replaced with:

```
val stateGetter: SharedFlow<MyState<myModel>> =
    myRepository.myCurr
        .map { DatabaseState.Success(myModel.curr) }
        .catch { _myState.emit(MyState.Error(it.cause))
        .shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L), replay = 1)
```

Also, I'm not sure if you intended to make your flow a shared flow in both the repository and the ViewModel.

Comment: Just a little more, and I'd have to copyright right you, as a partner for my project. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with using functions for getting values from db. Check this code as an example between the interaction of a repository and a view model:

```
class BooksRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
 private val libraryDatabase: LibraryDatabase) : BooksRepository {

override suspend fun insertBook(bookDomainEntity: BookDomainEntity): Either<Error, Success> {
    return try {
        Right(libraryDatabase.insertBookIntoLibrary(bookDomainEntity))
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        Left(DatabaseError)
    }
}
```

You can add a val property in a repository if you want to cache some data, of course it is not mandatory, you can still call a database for instance to get your data every time.

Below you can find how I call that method in my code:

```
fun insertBookIntoLibrary(bookEntity: BookDomainEntity) = flow {
    val libraryState = withContext(coroutineDispatcher) { repository.insertBook(Params(bookEntity)) }
    emit(libraryState.fold(
            ::handleError,
            ::handleSuccess))
    }.stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.Lazily,
            initialValue = Loading)
```